# How to filter the table in R, if I need value in the column either <-1.5 or >1.5?

Tags: r

I have a table. It looks like this:

`GeneID         LogFC       LogCPM      LR          Pvalue          FDR
Nfu_g_1_007790  1.3287961   8.54337803  19.02826    1.287965e-05    1.166020e-02
Nfu_g_1_012361  -2.2610532  0.80320879  18.85114    1.413268e-05    1.230250e-02
Nfu_g_1_022777  1.8288405   1.54772427  18.63845    1.580012e-05    1.297428e-02
Nfu_g_1_019366  -2.4299021  3.53515817  18.60843    1.605089e-05    1.297428e-02
Nfu_g_1_002006  0.8279454   4.06391236  18.40522    1.785683e-05    1.393633e-02
Nfu_g_1_008052  2.5998570   0.89062956  18.07316    2.125774e-05    1.603755e-02
...`

And I need to filter out (in one table) the rows where the second column (LogFC) is higher than 1.5 or lower than -1.5

Any suggestions?

Comment: `subset(df, LogFC > 1.5 | LogFC < -1.5)` ?

Comment: or subset(df, abs(LogFC)>1.5)